# python csv.writerow() stops working when I add code below

Tags: python, csv, path, python-os

The following code creates a CSV file with the headers I would like.

```
        import os
        import csv

        tempCSV = "03_26_09_41_21.BirdNET.results.csv"
        master_csv_path = os.path.join(r"C:\Users\owner\Documents\GitHub\SDP\master_CSVs", tempCSV[:5] + ".csv")
        
        if not os.path.exists(master_csv_path):
            f = open(master_csv_path, 'w', newline='')
            out = csv.writer(f)
            out.writerow(["Species", "Occurances", "Max Confidence", "Max Confidence Time", "Average Confidence"])    
            f.close()
```

However, when I add code to it, the CSV file from the snippet shown above is still created but is empty. I am not necessarily asking for confirmation that all the added code is correct but I can't understand why it would affect the creation of the csv in the if statement shown above. It seems to me like all the code I added shouldn't affect that if block and therefore the proper creation of the CSV. Any ideas?

```
        import os
        import csv
        import pandas as pd

        tempCSV = "03_26_09_41_21.BirdNET.results.csv"
        master_csv_path = os.path.join(r"C:\Users\owner\Documents\GitHub\SDP\master_CSVs", tempCSV[:5] + ".csv")
        temp_csv_path = os.path.join(r"C:\Users\owner\Documents\GitHub\SDP\BirdNET_CSVs", tempCSV)
        
        if not os.path.exists(master_csv_path):
            f = open(master_csv_path, 'w', newline='')
            out = csv.writer(f)
            out.writerow(["Species", "Occurances", "Max Confidence", "Max Confidence Time", "Average Confidence"])    
            f.close()
            
        with open(master_csv_path, 'w', newline='') as masterCSV, open(temp_csv_path, "r") as tempCSV:
            writer = csv.writer(masterCSV)
            try:
                data = pd.read_csv(master_csv_path)

                data.loc[masterCSV[3].at["Occurances"]] = int(data.loc[masterCSV[3].at["Occurances"]]) + 1

                if masterCSV[4] > float(data.loc[masterCSV[3].at["Max Confidence"]]):
                    data.loc[masterCSV[3].at["Max Confidence"]] = masterCSV[4]
                    data.loc[masterCSV[3].at["Max Confidence Time"]] = hour + ':' + minute

                data.loc[masterCSV[3].at["Average Confidence"]] = (int(data.loc[masterCSV[3].at["Average Confidence"]]) * (int(data.loc[masterCSV[3].at["Occurances"]]) - 1) + masterCSV[4]) / int(data.loc[masterCSV[3].at["Occurances"]])
                
            except (KeyError, IndexError) as error:
                writer.writerow([tempCSV[3], 1, tempCSV[4], hour + ':' + minute, tempCSV[4]])
```

Comment: Don't open the same file twice with `'w'`. Opening for write truncates the file so you'll lose the header the second time.  Either do `'a'` (append) on the second instance, or just leave the first instance open and continue to write to it.

Comment: I'd take @MarkTolonen second suggestion of just opening the file once, when you're finally ready to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it thanks to the suggestion of @MarkTolonen. I took out the part where I opened the same file twice. Updated code shown below.

```
...
if not os.path.exists(master_csv_path):
        with open(master_csv_path, 'w', newline='') as masterCSV:
            writer = csv.writer(masterCSV)
            writer.writerow(["Species", "Occurances", "Max Confidence", "Max Confidence Time", "Average Confidence"])
        
 with open(temp_csv_path, "r") as tempCSV:
     ...
```

Comment: Great. You can accept your answer, too, to show that the question/problem was satisfied.